# Maven multi module project lifecycle

Tags: java, maven, build

I have a large multi module maven project and am using the compiler, surefire and failsafe plugins. All of my unit tests run with surefire, and my integration tests with failsafe. Why running `mvn verify` on the whole project, it appears to do the following:

1. Get the next module to run (based on dependency graph)
2. Execute the full lifecycle for that module (initialize, compile, test, integration-test, ...)
3. Repeat until no more modules

This is a really slow process and I feel like it would be faster if it did the following:

1. Compile all modules
2. Run unit tests on all modules
3. Run integration tests on all modules

Effectively doing something like:

1. Execute the current phase for all modules
2. Move to the next phase, repeat

However I can't figure out how to set this up. Is this possible? Or is my hypothesis that this might be faster off? Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1):

You can't do that, consider following structure

```
A (pom)
|
|
|
|
------B (jar)
|     \---C (dependency) 
|
|------C (jar)
```

here B depends on C, now you for example you have following classes in B & C respectively

B

```
class B{
 C c;
 public void sayHello(){
    c.sayHello();
 }
}
```

C

```
class C {
  public void sayHello(){}
 }
```

now you change C class to

```
 class C {
  public void sayHello(String name){}
 }
```

and if you do compile on all phase it will start from A - C  - B  (dependency graph), C compiled fine (compile just compiles source and copies classes to target/classes), now you are running compile on B it will compile fine because it will take B's older version from local maven cache (where it still has method without any param)

now install happens on C first and on B it will go SUCCESSFUL

next attempts of the same thing will fail, because B will now find different method signature

What would be effective here is incremental build, however maven doesn't quite support incremental build in true sense, [see here is the open request for that](https://jira.codehaus.org/browse/MNG-5523)

if you want just test executions saperate from build life cycle you can do it using separate build profile