# Development practices when actively developing both JAR and dependent JARs?

Tags: java, maven, jenkins

Yeah, I know, the title sucks - it's as descriptive as I could get.

I'm trying to get my brain around the concept of developing a JAR when you have dependent JARs that are also under development, and how to build locally as well as using CI (Jenkins). Here's the setup:

Let's say I have a Maven project (Java code) that creates a nice, self-deploying JAR called KillerApplicationSpaceship. This project depends on, among many third party libraries (as managed dependencies) a couple JARs that I am also developing. Call them KillerLibraryLister and KillerLibraryRimmer. They have their own Maven projects. I can drop into any of them and "mvn compile" any time I like and life is grand.

I have a Jenkins installation on a machine that monitors the GitHub repositories for all three projects. Whenever a code change is pushed a build is triggered. KillerApplicationSpaceship is also triggered to build whenever KillerLibraryLister or KillerLibraryRimmer has a successful build. All three JARs are pushed to a Maven repository when they're built, and KillerApplicationSpaceship specifies the two libraries as managed dependencies in this repository. Life is wonderful, EXCEPT that making a change to either of the libraries, while kicking off a build of KillerApplicationSpaceship, doesn't pick up changes to the libraries! Their version numbers don't change, so the cached version of the library is always used.

In this modern world in which we live in, how does one properly do development on the libraries and ensure that each build of the library is picked up by KillerApplicationSpaceship when it builds? Is there a way to say "always retrieve this JAR from the repository. Always, always?"

Now let's take it a step further. I'm also able to build these projects locally, of course. I want to be able to "mvn clean package" KillerApplicationSpaceship on my local machine - but the POM specifies that the two libraries are managed dependencies in the Maven repository. As I mentioned, my Jenkins box pushes them to my development repository on a successful build, but this is problematic during development for two reasons:

First, as above, I don't seem to get the latest version even if there's been a change because the version number doesn't change.

Second, and more importantly, while doing development, I'm not pushing to GitHub with every small change, but locally I want to compile and test often. Locally.

How do I reference my LOCAL build of the KillerLibraryLister and KillerLibraryRimmer projects? If I make them unmanaged in KillerApplicationStarship, then my Jenkins box expects them unmanaged, too - since we're all using the same POM.

Seems to me that what I want is for a LOCAL build on my local machine to reference the latest local build of each of the two libraries, but if being built on the Jenkins box, reference the latest version in the Maven repository, as that is the last checked-in version. I have no clue how I'd do this, of course.

This can get a little more constrained in that the library JARs are consumed by other applications, one of which, for example, is built using SBT (it's a Scala application using Scalatra). So making a parent POM with modules isn't an option here. The SBT project has a build.scala file that specifies the library JAR files on a remote Maven repository. But surely I don't want to have to push these JARs to the repository *every time* I make a code change to them (remember, they're under active development, too).

There's got to be a simple chapter in a favorite book that 'splains this all, conceptually, yes? I'm probably missing the obvious "best practice" for this kind of development.

I've been doing web-dev and single-monolithic-projects for the past five or six years, so this is a paradigm shift for me. The code I get. The project management and build practices have me needing some catching up.

Many thanks for any adult supervision! ;)

Answer (score 0):

there are two solution to your problem

- either make all your projects inside a single maven project tree and build them all once, so there is no chance of being out of sync

of if you can't do above

- develop against releases not the snapshot, so for example your project A consumes B as dependency when you want to change B's code make a release and bump the dependency version in project A to get specific build

Comment: This doesn't make sense to me. How does one do development like this? This contemplates code that's ready for release. Remember, the issue is developing both the application *AND* the libraries at the same time. So I'm making changes to the libraries *AND* the application that consumes them.

Comment: For sake of narrowing two down to one, as well, presume that the application is built in Scala using SBT and includes multiple JARs built out of Java using Maven. Now we can't combine them (I throw this out there as an example to concentrate on how to do development when you have disparate projects, both in development)

Comment: which option doesn't make sense to you

Comment: The second one. It presumes that EVERY TIME I make a code change in B I have to push a release build. During development, that could be hundreds of times a day as I write code, debug, test, etc. That's surely untenable.

This is for *active development*

Comment: if that is too frequent you should have them as part of single maven project tree, you build once and all gets built

Comment: As I said, they're not a single project nor can they be. The libraries are consumed by an application, but they're also consumed by MANY applications, including applications that aren't Java or built with Maven (for example, one application is Scala, built with SBT, that has many of these libraries as dependencies)

Comment: I am not saying put it as single maven project, but keep them as different maven project as modules in a maven project hierarchy

Comment: see : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22389877/maven-multi-module-project-lifecycle

Comment: If the application is built by SBT and includes JARs that are built by Maven, how would that be accomplished? The build.scala file specifies an artifact in a remote Maven repository.